# Drupal 7 module shell_exec issue

Tags: php, linux, command-line, drupal-7, shell-exec

I am attempting to create a file on my Linux server containing XML output via PHP.

I am using the following line of code:

```
print "CHECKING: " . shell_exec("echo {$output} > tested.xml");
```

The $output variable contains well formated XML and I am trying to dynamically create tested.xml and populate it ... but it doesn't work.

AMENDED:

I just tried the following approach:

```
print "CHECKING: " . shell_exec("echo {$output} > /var/www/mysite/sites/all/modules/my_module/output/tested.xml");
```

I then gave the output directory full 777 permissions but my XML file still does not get created.

Comment: Use [`escapeshellarg($output)`](http://us.php.net/escapeshellarg) . Why are you using shell exec for something that can be done via plain PHP functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing missing in the code provided is an absolute path designation in the redirect specified in the shell_exec command.  Assuming the OS user the web server is running as (e.g., 'apache') has write access to the destination directory, then the output will be written to the file specified in the IO redirect.

For example, in order to write the output of the XML file to /tmp, use the following code:

```
print "CHECKING: " . shell_exec("echo {$output} > /tmp/tested.xml");
```

**AMENDED:**

Rather than provide an answer of my own I decided to build on your good work :-)
Your suggestion worked with full XML tags with the following slightly adjusted code:

```
print "CHECKING: " . shell_exec("echo '{$output}' > /tmp/tested.xml");
```

*ps: And you were also correct that a full path to an apache permitted directory within which the file will be created is absolutely necessary.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried your approach but it has not worked. I updated my question above with the changes I made

Comment: "Well formed XML" will contain plenty of `<` and `>` by itself.

Comment: You are right! I tried 'output' instead of $output and my tested.xml document was created. But now, how do I get the < and > tags issue dealt with so my XML output works???